# How to loop and open all csv files in my current folder in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I randomly create a new folder on my desktop, in this folder I have one template file with .xlsm extension, which contains my VBA code. Meanwhile I have several csv files saved in the same folder with my raw data.

The purpose is looping through all those csv files one by one, open it, and copy some data and paste to my template file(I know how to do this part) from it and close it after all operations are done.

Currently I meet a problem about how to loop through my folder and open those csv one by one. I didn't set a specific folder name, since I want to share it with other people to use,therefore I use Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path to get the path for my current folder.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Range_End_Method()
Dim Dir As String
Dim i As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dir = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
For Each i In Dir.Files
    Debug.Print i.Name
    If (i.Name Like "*.csv") Then
      Workbooks.Open (i.Path)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem you are having

Comment: I don't understand why you'd use VBA for this, when Power Query does it so well.

Comment: ... as does powershell, batch, VBScript and any other number of scripting languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to use the Dir function. To use that, make a call to it, specifying folder and file type in the first call, then call it empty until it returns an empty string. Like this:

```
Folder = Dir(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*.csv")
Do While Folder <> ""
    Debug.Print Folder
    Workbooks.Open Folder
    Folder = Dir()
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function and macro.
Juste replace MsgBox (myFile + "OK") by the action you want to execute.

**FUNCTION**

```
Function ClasseurOuvert(NomFich)
On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks(NomFich).Activate
    If Err <> 0 Then Workbooks.Open FileName:=NomFich
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

**MACRO**

```
Sub LoopFiles()

Dim myPath As String, myFile As String

myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

myFile = Dir(myPath & "\*.*")

Do While myFile <> "" And myFile Like "*.csv"

    Call ClasseurOuvert(myPath & "\" & myFile)

    With Workbooks(myFile)

    MsgBox (myFile + "OK")

    End With
    Workbooks(myFile).Save

    Workbooks(myFile).Close

    myFile = Dir()

Loop

End Sub
```